# I have i18next translation problems

Tags: reactjs, function, local-storage, i18next

I have a question. I can change the language with i18next, everything is fine. But for example, if we get our data from an api or some data.js file, what should we do? For example i have data in data.js file and how should I change the language when writing this data on the screen on some page

```js
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const { t } = useTranslation()

const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: t('singleCard.0.title'), (this way doesnt work)
        category: t('singleCard.0.category'),
        price: 15.99,
        img: '../images/item-1.jpeg',
        desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'diner double',
        category: 'lunch',
        price: 13.99,
        img: '../images/item-2.jpeg',
        desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'godzilla milkshake',
        category: 'shakes',
        price: 6.99,
        img: '../images/item-3.jpeg',
        desc: `ombucha chillwave fanny pack 3 wolf moon street art photo booth before they sold out organic viral.`,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'country delight',
        category: 'breakfast',
        price: 20.99,
        img: '../images/item-4.jpeg',
        desc: `Shabby chic keffiyeh neutra snackwave pork belly shoreditch. Prism austin mlkshk truffaut, `,
    },
];

export default data
```